# How to transfer GET data from one server to another using CURL?

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl

I have two Servers:

**1. Licensing**

**2. Provisioning**

Now a client(android/ios device) sends a request to license server. So there we get some parameters from **GET** which I want to forward to Provisioning server, using CURL.

**This code is on License Server**

```
  $skey = $this->input->get('site_id');
  $uid  = $this->input->get('user_id'); 
  $url =  "http://127.0.0.1/provisioning/customer/provisioning?site_key=".$skey."&uid=".$uid;

  $wget_cmd = "wget --no-check-certificate \"".$url."\" >/dev/null 2>/dev/null ";
  //echo($wget_cmd);
  //exec($wget_cmd);
  // create a new cURL resource
  $ch = curl_init();
  //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, TRUE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 300);
  // set URL and other appropriate options
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
  // grab URL and pass it to the browser
  curl_exec($ch);


  echo curl_error($ch);


  // close cURL resource, and free up system resources
  curl_close($ch);
```

On the **Provisioning Server** How to access these variables?:

```
$skey = $this->input->get('site_id');
$uid  = $this->input->get('user_id');
```

**I don't want to echo them on screen** I Just want to use them for other DB transactions.

Comment: Seems you already have those in URL.

Comment: @Tpojka i just discovered that i can access it by doing $this->db->get('uid'); in provisioning

Comment: Sure thing. That's CI way to get query parameter.

Comment: I was on provisioning server and i was trying $this->db->get('user_id'); so i never got it

Comment: It depends on keys in query string. If it is `uid`, you need to check it over `$_GET['uid']` or implicitly `$this->input->get('uid')` if CodeIgniter.

Comment: Yeah i understood it now thanks for your time

Comment: At a start you are trying to use site_id and user_id on your provisioning server code you show above and you are passing along site_key and uid in the License Server.